# Why does some of my components such as JLabel and JComboBox sometimes not appear after using a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, jcombobox

I'm trying to transition from the home screen to the option menu through a JButton by adding a JPanel (menu) to the frame and hiding the currently visible panel (background). I'm using an Action Listener to activate the transition. **Sometimes when running the code (more like most of the time), some parts of the menu won't appear such as the JComboBox and two of the JLabels.** I'm not having an issue with the JSlider though, but I haven't been able to identify the problem for the other components. I tried implementing `menu.revalidate()` and `menu.setVisible(true)` at the end of my code, but to no prevail. I also tried doing `frame.revalidate()` and `frame.setVisible(true)`. Another attempt at fixing this was by moving around the `menu.add([insert JLabel/JComboBox])`.

The code that I used is as provided

Window.java

```
JFrame frame;
JPanel background;
JPanel menu;
JSlider difficulty;
JLabel difficultyLabel;
JComboBox exerciseChoice;
JPanel dropDownPanel;
JLabel exerciseChoiceLabel;
JPanel difficultyPanel;

public ActionListener startButtonPressed() throws IOException {
      ActionListener temp = 
         new ActionListener() {
         
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               try {
                  background.setVisible(false);
                  menu = new JPanel();
                  menu.setLayout(new BoxLayout (menu, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));   
                  menu.setBounds(menu.getLocation().x+50, 50, 700, 100);
                  menu.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                  startButton.setEnabled(false);
                  createDifficultySlider(); 
                  createWorkoutDropDown();
                  
                  frame.add(menu);
                  frame.setVisible(true);
               
               } catch (IOException r) {}
            }
         
         };
      return temp;
   
   }
   
   public void createWorkoutDropDown() throws IOException {
      dropDownPanel = new JPanel();
      dropDownPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
      dropDownPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      String[] choices = {"Abs", "Cardio", "Full Body", "Upper Body", "Stretches", "Lower Body"};
      exerciseChoice = new JComboBox(choices);
      exerciseChoice.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 20));
      exerciseChoiceLabel = new JLabel("Workout Options");
      exerciseChoiceLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 20));
      dropDownPanel.add(exerciseChoiceLabel);
      dropDownPanel.add(exerciseChoice);
      menu.add(dropDownPanel);
      
      
   }
   
   public void createDifficultySlider() throws IOException {
      difficultyPanel = new JPanel();
      difficultyPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
      difficultyPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      difficulty = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 1, 10, 5);
      difficulty.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(difficulty.getPreferredSize().width + 60, difficulty.getPreferredSize().height + 5));
      difficultyLabel = new JLabel("Difficulty Level (Easy 1- Hard 10)");  
      difficultyLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 20));
      difficulty.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 10)); 
      difficulty.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
      difficulty.setPaintLabels(true);
      difficulty.setPaintTicks(true);
      difficulty.setSnapToTicks(true);
      difficultyPanel.add(difficultyLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      difficultyPanel.add(difficulty, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
      menu.add(difficultyPanel); 
   
   }
```

EDIT: I had to throw IOExceptions because I was importing fonts from my drive.

Comment: Hi. You can tag your question with the `swing` tag which may attract more attention AFAIU. As for your code, you can use a `CardLayout` (see [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)) in case you want to reuse the same container/window/frame. Otherwise you would have to do this somewhat manually (ie remove contents, then add new contents, then revalidate).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I updated the post and will look into your suggestion.

Comment: No problem. Actually [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33663034) answer on another post is an example on how to do it. Replace `MainMenu` with your home screen panel and `StartMenu` with your option menu panel.

Comment: This is a lot easier than what I was going for. Thank you so much for your help.